# php серверное время time()

Tags: php

Почему серверное время (timestamp) echo time(); на странице возвращает не UTC, а локальное? Переводил получаемое значение в дату с помощью https://www.epochconverter.com/... date_default_timezone_get(); возвращает "UTC"

Comment: phpinfo что говорит?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan php info большой, что более точней вам предоставить?

Comment: Функция time() по умолчанию возвращает локальное время сервера. Если вам нужно время UTC, используйте date_default_timezone_set("UTC").

Comment: @fixer я же писал, что date_default_timezone_get(); возвращает "UTC", зачем еще писать set?

Comment: Потому что date_default_timezone_get() не всегда корректно работает при определенных [условиях](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date-default-timezone-get.php), если функции не удается определить параметр из настроек системы, она возвращает UTC. А параметр, задаваемый с помощью date_default_timezone_set(), является приоритетным.